# Where was the Ixcanha Maya community located during the Caste War of the Yucatán?

Tags: native-americans, mexico, maya

There is mention of a Mayan community of about a thousand people during the Caste War of the Yucatán who refused to break with the Catholic Church. I am trying to figure out where their community was located.

> Another rebel group, the [Ixcanha Maya community](https://indigenousmexico.org/campeche/indigenous-quintana-roo-the-last-two-centuries-part-2/), lived in the jungles of the lower center of the peninsula.

Is their community synonymous with the settlement at X-Canhá?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Descriptions of the location of this group are confused. Not only was their population modest, the spelling varies, and there are few landmarks in the jungle. Probably it is the Xcanhá shown on the map in the article you cited.

[Odile Hoffman](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01287334/document) locates the Ixcanha east of Chan Santa Cruz, but this [map from Martha H. Villalobos González](http://recaribe.uqroo.mx/numeros/anteriores/15/152villalobos.pdf) shows their range west of it:

[image: Yucatec tribal ranges]